# Rails 5 - render partial on conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue** - Rails is not rendering my partial even though the conditional is true

**Inspecting params returns the following:**

`Parameters: {"operating_system"=>"Red Hat Linux 7"}`

**Method 1** - Not Working

```
# app/views/forms/_show.html.erb

<%= form_with model: @form, local: true, id: 'new_form' do |f| %>
  <% if params[:operating_system] == 'Red Hat Linux 7' %>
    <%= render 'section_two', f: f %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Method 2** - Not Working

```
# app/views/forms/_show.html.erb

<%= form_with model: @form, local: true, id: 'new_form' do |f| %>
  <%= render 'section_two', f: f if params[:operating_system] == 'Red Hat Linux 7' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try `<%- if` instead of `<% if`

Comment: `<%-` just removes the whitespace outside the erb tag @jvillian

Comment: Are you sure the conditional is true?  You may want to add `<pre><%= params[:operating_system] %></pre>` to test if the conditional is true.

Comment: Both are functionally the same and will differ only in whitespace in the rendered html. But your results can't be reproduced. Are you sure you have eliminated potential errors like if the string for example contains a non-breaking space?

Comment: Ah, thanks, @max! Learn something new everyday.

Comment: @TomAranda - I have rendered the params and inspected them. I can see `<ActionController::Parameters {"operating_system"=>"Red Hat Linux 7"} permitted: false>`

Comment: I think the issue is that you are using symbol. Just use string `params["operating_system"]`. Symbols and Strings are not always treated as same

Answer (score 1):

Since the code you have does not contain how the operating_system parameter is passed to the controller, I am assuming the issue is with the way you are using the key with `params`. If `params` is a normal `Hash`, then try using `params["operating_system"]` instead of `params[:operating_system]`.

`"operating_system"` and `:operating_system` are not the same for a normal `Hash` object.

However, using a string vs symbol will not matter if `params` is the default object that you get in a Rails controller, as that `params` is a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` object.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I did change it to `params["operating_system"]`, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

After consulting with some IRC folks, apparently, the problem is that I am redirecting from one action to another action. During the redirect, `redirect_to` triggers a fresh request; thus losing all my params.

I understand that I did not post my controller methods, and I thought it was not necessary ... apparently it was necessary to answer this question!

My fault!